# How do I add 'Rect's or text to a sprite in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to recreate a [slide puzzle](http://a413.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/072/Purple/v4/b4/fe/56/b4fe565e-7c61-65e1-4e6d-79de195a2d50/mzl.eylgjhju.png) and I need to print to text to previously drawn rectangular sprites. This is how I set them up:

```
class Tile(Entity):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILE_SIZE-1,TILE_SIZE-1))
        self.image.fill(LIGHT_BLUE)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,TILE_SIZE-1,TILE_SIZE-1)
        self.isSelected = False
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms',22) # Font for the text is defined
```

And this is how I've draw them:

```
def drawTiles(self):
    number = 0
    number_of_tiles = 15

    x = 0
    y = 1

    for i in range(number_of_tiles):
        label = self.font.render(str(number),True,WHITE) # Where the label is defined. I just want it to print 0's for now.
        x += 1
        if x > 4:
            y += 1
            x = 1

        tile = Tile(x*TILE_SIZE,y*TILE_SIZE)
        tile.image.blit(label,[x*TILE_SIZE+40,y*TILE_SIZE+40]) # How I tried to print text to the sprite. It didn't show up and didn't error, so I suspect it must have been drawn behind the sprite.
        tile_list.append(tile)
```

This is how I tried to add Rect's (when it is clicked on with the mouse):

```
# Main program loop
for tile in tile_list:
    screen.blit(tile.image,tile.rect)
    if tile.isInTile(pos):
        tile.isSelected = True
        pygame.draw.rect(tile.image,BLUE,[tile.rect.x,tile.rect.y,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE],2)
    else:
        tile.isSelected = False
```

isInTile:

```
def isInTile(self,mouse_pos):
    if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos): return True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately you don't have enough information available to answer your question. You only provide the current code, however in order to answer your question we need to know 3 things. 1: What exactly is wrong, is it not displaying right, offset, not at all? 2. Is the code running correctly, I.E. not crashing. and 3. What have you tried and how has it not worked. Please take these into consideration, and then edit your question accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: I recommend you this book [Making Games with python](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/) I read that to learn programming with pygame. I'm not sure if it is chapter 6 or 7, but there is an slide puzzle example source code very well explained (You can download a pdf for free in that link, very useful to pygame library)

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13, I thought it was pretty clear what I was asking. I want to know how to add pygame.Rects and text to rectangular sprites. I commented in the code where I thought the problem was happening and what I thought was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates in Pygame are relative to the surface that's being drawn on. The way you're currently drawing the rects on tile.image makes it draw at (tile.rect.x, tile.rect.y) relative to the topleft of tile.image. Most times tile.rect.x and tile.rect.y will be greater than the tile width and height, so it will be invisible. What you probably want is pygame.draw.rect(tile.image,BLUE,[0,0,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE],2). This draws a rectangle on the tile from the topleft (0,0) of the tile to the bottom right (TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE).

The same goes for the text. For example if TILE_SIZE is 25 and x is 2, the x coordinate where the text is blit on tile.image is 2*25+40 = 90. 90 is bigger than the width of tile.image (which was TILE_SIZE-1=24), so it will draw outside of the surface, making it invisible. If you want to draw the text in the top left corner of tile.image, do tile.image.blit(label, [0,0]).